# What is the syntax of adding a key and a value to nested dictionary in python?

Tags: python, dictionary

I need to add keys and values to the dictionary, that are nested inside a list. I can also probably use a dictionary only, but then I can't use **.append** and it will be a different syntax.

```py
# Dictionary format
bids_log = [{
    "bidder_name": "",
    "bid": ""
  }]
```

How can I shrink two lines of code into one line, please?

```py
bids_record["name"] = bidder_name
bids_record["bid"] = bid
bids_log.append(bids_record)
```

Actual Desired Output:  [{'name': 'tomas', 'bid': '11'}]

```
# bids_record = {bidder_name: bid}
# bids_log.append(bids_record)
```

Actual Output: [{'lukas': '23'}, {'tomas': '33'}]

I need to put "bidder_name" and "bid" as Key and Value in front of each record. Now the variables name and bid are Key and Value

I hope that makes sense :), thank you!

Comment: Not sure what you are after, perhaps `bids_log.append({"name":bidder_name, "bid":bid})`.

Comment: Thank you @tdelaney , this is what I needed and it worked. I'm trying to write it clearly, but I'm still at the beginning of python :), thanks for your patience guys.

Comment: Go ahead and accept the answer below that does the same thing. Then we know its done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [@tdelany](https://stackoverflow.com/users/642070/tdelaney) mentioned in the comments, you can use:

```
bids_log.append({
    "name": bidder_name, 
    "bid": bid
})
```